# How do I know when I've eaten too much Royal Jelly? Will the side-effect stay for a long time if i do?

Tags: the-council

I understand consuming "too much" of Royal Jelly will cause you side effects. How much Royal Jelly is "too much"? Will that effect go away (after consuming golden elixir or sleeping)? Or will it stay with the character?